# How to transform Formulas to Python?

Tags: python, matrix, formula, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I want to use two Formulas of a [Paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.106.7999&rep=rep1&type=pdf) in Python.

This Formula:
[image]

I translated it to this code:

```
P = A               #(size 24x24)
Q = B               #(size 24x24)
sum_of_all = 0
    for row in range(0,P.shape[0]):
        for column in range (0,P.shape[1]):
            zwischen =(w.iloc[row] * np.power((abs(P[row, column])-abs(Q[row,column])),2))[0]
            sum_of_all = sum_of_all +zwischen
res = np.sqrt(sum_of_all)
```

The other Formula:

[image]

I translated it to this code:

```
P = A 
Q = B
sum_of_all = 0
for row in range(0,P.shape[0]):
    for column in range (0,P.shape[1]):
        zwischen = P[row, column]*Q[row,column]
        sum_of_all = sum_of_all +zwischen
sum_of_all = (w.iloc[row])[0]*abs(sum_of_all)        
res = np.sqrt(2-(2*sum_of_all))
```

1. Did I do it right?
2. How can I change (especially Formula 1) in a pythonic way, because those Formulas are used really often (30000 times) and through them the loop is getting really slow.

Comment: Why do you have your weight w in a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Why not? Does it make a difference if it is a dataframe or a numpy array?

Comment: If you worry about performance go for the smallest data structure to do the job. Although it's unlikely that you get too much extra when going to a numpy array. Also, it has to do with how easy to interpret and maintain the code. Otherwise, in your first "function" you should precompute the absolute value on your matrices A and B (or as you alias them P and Q) with the proper numpy element-wise abs function instead of abs that apparently is from the std library (you don't show your imports). Then the subtraction can also be done with numpy instead of the for loop.

Comment: Last comment, if you want to know if you did it right the best way is to try with a small example like a 2x2 or 3x3 A, B matrices and do it by hand and compare with the solution you get with the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find if you use numpy a lot of things "just work". Now I couldn't actually test this as you gave no test data, but the first formula should be something like

```
P = np.random.rand(24, 24)
Q = np.random.rand(24, 24)
w = np.random.rand(24, 1)

np.sqrt(np.sum((w * np.power((np.abs(P) - np.abs(Q)), 2))))
```

It shouldn't massively matter if your weights are in a dataframe or numpy array - a dataframe is backed onto a numpy array anyway so using array operations like this should work fine. It does add an overhead, however, and for weights doesn't really makes sense to use (my rule of thumb is if your data has meaningful column names, use a dataframe, otherwise a plain numpy array should be enough)